# Can't connect to FTP with Catalina Beta

Tags: ftp, catalina

Since upgrading to Catalina Beta, FileZilla, Transmit & Finder software fails to connect to the remote host.

FileZilla gives error:

```
Status:         Connection attempt failed with "EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host", trying next address.
Status:         Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status:         Connection attempt failed with "EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host".
```

The same credentials work on Macs with Mojave 10.14.4.

The Firewall on the Catalina Beta is not on.

How do I get FTP working on Catalina Beta?

Comment: "all FTP software" what specific software? If its an App you may need to wait for the developer to update it for compatibility with Catalina. I can tell you that I have had success connecting to FTP with Finder > Go > Connect To Server

Comment: Sry, FileZilla & Transmit fail to connect. Finder fails to connect also.

Comment: Can you ping the host in question? Can you run `telnet HOST 21` and get through?

Comment: I can ping the host in question. I can't install telnet because I can't install homebrew, because Terminal can't connect to github.

Comment: I don't have an answer yet.  This seems to be a larger issue.  I have added to this forum on the Apple Developer website: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125519.  This issue may also be affecting npm transactions.

Comment: I also get that the client is searching for '/' as the FTP directory.  I have a similar issue when trying to install npm packages via terminal.  I've created that question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374598/npm-installation-issues-with-macos-10-15-2-beta-1.  I think the two are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari was slow also.

Checking network settings, I see a hide.me VPN active.

Disabling this resolved the issue.

No idea how the VPN got installed.