# Safari slow on Catalina Beta

Tags: safari, catalina

Since installing macOS Catalina Beta, Safari takes 5 minutes or more to load google.com.

I've cleared History but the issue remains.

I also have a [related problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367250/cant-connect-to-ftp-with-catalina-beta) in that my FTP software fails to connect now with Catalina Beta (Transmit & FileZilla).

How do I troubleshoot this please?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the network settings I saw a hide.me VPN active.

Disabling this resolved the issue.

No idea how it got installed.