# NPM installation issues with MacOS 10.15.2 beta 1

Tags: macos, catalina, ftp, beta-seed-program

So, I've got an issue that may be related to this question: [Can't connect to FTP with Catalina Beta](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367250/cant-connect-to-ftp-with-catalina-beta)

I've been trying to npm install Bootstrap and Font-Awesome on an Angular application.  Should be a routine job with no problems.  Now, I'm getting errors like this

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.9/fse-v1.2.9-node-v79-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.9 and node@13.1.0 (node-v79 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
```

What's bugging me is the '/' part.  This is the same thing I am seeing when I try to access a pre-configured FTP site via multiple FTP clients.  I can access the FTP from other devices [non-Mac] but haven't had a chance to check older MacOS versions.

How can I determine if this is a beta issue, an NPM issue, an FTP issue, or perhaps I'm hitting a new firewall setup by my IT department?

### *** UPDATE ***

It would appear that the root of this issue is centered around the fsevents package that npm is trying to install.  This is indicated in other reports on this issue in other places.

https://github.com/prixe/lindo/issues/48

https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/278

Comment: Are you running a VPN like the related question?

Comment: bmike... no I'm not running a VPN, but I did rule out the firewall as I attempted this via home network and got the same issue.  Also, the FTP similarity may be coincidental.  More than likely this is an NPM issue related to the fsevents package that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

Remove most of this:

```
The root cause of the issue is the updating of the fsevents binaries by the author.  Once they do that, the issue should be resolved.

The fsevents team has provided recommendations to resolve in the meantime via their github issues page.

https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/291
```

I went back to the drawing board.  It turns out that when I looked at the github issue closer, someone actually nailed the root cause with this handy little tidbit.

> This is not something to be "fixed". One needs to have XCode
>   command-line tools installed in order to install/compile native
>   modules.
>
> There no longer are credentials for AWS. So the installs are actually
>   a bit risky. In addition 1.2.x is really deprecated. I've just done a
>   release that removes node-pre-gyp dependency and therefore the
>   ability/failure to download prebuilt binaries.

I had just re-installed Xcode but had neglected to add the CLT.  Done... Fixed the problem.

Comment: do you re-install Xcode with CLT or NOT with CLT? It would be nice if you can elaborate more.

Comment: Just make sure you have the CLT [Command Line Tools] installed.  If you are using the newest version of XCode you shouldn't have to install them separately anymore.